# How do I shorten input line for command prompt (for SymmetricDB tutorial)?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I'm running batch files and getting an error "The input line is too long. The syntax of the command is wrong." I'm hoping you can help solve this error.

A few more details:

I'm working through a tutorial for SymmetricDB found here: http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/2.5/pdf/user-guide.pdf

I'm in Section 2.2 "Creating and Populating Your Databases", on Step 2, where I have to run a command "sym". Details are in the pdf.

I have all of *no* experience with batch files and very little command line experience. Having searched around, it seems that full directory paths are being insert into commands within the batch file, causing commands longer than Windows allows, but I'm not 100% clear on what I need to do to resolve it.

For reference, below is the contents of the sym batch file (I can copy additional content if helpful). There's also a plain sym file, copied at the bottom.

Many thanks,
Jody

```
@REM license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed
@REM with this work for additional information regarding
@REM copyright ownership.  JumpMind Inc licenses this file
@REM to you under the GNU General Public License, version 3.0 (GPLv3)
@REM (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
@REM with the License.
@REM
@REM You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License,
@REM version 3.0 (GPLv3) along with this library; if not, see
@REM <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
@REM
@REM Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
@REM software distributed under the License is distributed on an
@REM "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
@REM KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
@REM specific language governing permissions and limitations
@REM under the License.
@REM

@echo off

set PRGDIR=%~dp0
set HOMEDIR=%PRGDIR%..
set CONFDIR=%HOMEDIR%\conf
set CLASSPATH=%HOMEDIR%\patches

for %%i in ("%HOMEDIR%\lib\*.jar") do call "%PRGDIR%cpappend.bat" %%i

for %%i in ("%HOMEDIR%\web\WEB-INF\lib\*.jar") do call "%PRGDIR%cpappend.bat" %%i

rem echo CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%

java  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=../tmp -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Duser.language=en -Djava.io.tmpdir=../tmp -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=800000 -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormKeys=100000 -Dsym.keystore.file="%HOMEDIR%\security\keystore" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="%HOMEDIR%\security\cacerts" -Dlog4j.configuration="file:%CONFDIR%\log4j.xml" -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=1800000 -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=1800000 org.jumpmind.symmetric.SymmetricLauncher %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Plain .sym file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Run commandline support through SymmetricLauncher
#
PRGDIR=`dirname "$0"`
if [ "$PRGDIR" = "" ]
then
   PRGDIR=`echo $0 | sed 's/\/sym//g'`
fi
if [ "$PRGDIR" = "" ]
then
   PRGDIR="."
fi
LIBDIR=$PRGDIR/../lib
WEBLIBDIR=$PRGDIR/../web/WEB-INF/lib
LOG4JXML="file:$PRGDIR/../conf/log4j.xml"
RUNJAVA=java
if [ -n "log4j.xml" -a -f "log4j.xml" ]
then
   LOG4JXML="file:$PRGDIR/log4j.xml"
fi
if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]
then
   RUNJAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
CLASSPATH=../patches
SEP=:
if uname | grep -i cygwin > /dev/null
then
   SEP=";"
fi
for jar in $LIBDIR/*
do
   CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}${SEP}${jar}
done
for jar in $WEBLIBDIR/*
do
   CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}${SEP}${jar}
done
#echo $CLASSPATH
exec "$RUNJAVA" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=../tmp -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Duser.language=en -Djava.io.tmpdir=../tmp -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=800000 -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormKeys=100000 -Dsym.keystore.file="$PRGDIR/../security/keystore" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="$PRGDIR/../security/cacerts" -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=1800000 -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=1800000 -Dlog4j.configuration=$LOG4JXML -cp $CLASSPATH org.jumpmind.symmetric.SymmetricLauncher "$@"
```

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit is the OS, ran from cmd.exe

Comment: cmd doesn't read `(ba)sh` scripts.

Comment: Thanks Endoro. That means I wasn't clear in my explanation. Whatever type the script/file is described above, the problem still exists. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the error coming from Java or the shell? Are you certain the syntax of the java command _is_ correct?

Comment: On the last line, add `echo ` before the `java` command and a pause on the following line.  You will see how many parameters are being used and the actual contents of the command.  If you are using XP then the command length is 8K but prior to XP it was less.  If the paths can be dispensed with then you could use `%~nx1 %~nx2 %~nx3 %~nx4 %~nx5 %~nx6` etc. in place of `%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6`

Answer (score 0):

The only java I know is caffeine-related - nevertheless, you could try breaking the `JAVA` line

```
java whatever whatever whatever^
 and so on war and peace^
 are you sure it is not COBOL %*
```

Where the caret (<kbd>^</kbd>) is cmd's line-continuation character and `%*` means "all of the procedure's parameters"